# Multiple triggers

Tags: t-sql

Can we call trigger that contain invocation of multiple triggersw on a single button click event?

as there are two triggers as follows:

**First fires after insertion:**

```
CREATE TRIGGER trgAfterInsert ON [dbo].[Employee_Test] 
FOR INSERT
AS
    declare @empid int;
    declare @empname varchar(100);
    declare @empsal decimal(10,2);
    declare @audit_action varchar(100);

    select @empid=i.Emp_ID from inserted i; 
    select @empname=i.Emp_Name from inserted i; 
    select @empsal=i.Emp_Sal from inserted i;   
    set @audit_action='Inserted Record -- After Insert Trigger.';

    insert into Employee_Test_Audit
           (Emp_ID,Emp_Name,Emp_Sal,Audit_Action,Audit_Timestamp) 
    values(@empid,@empname,@empsal,@audit_action,getdate());

    PRINT 'AFTER INSERT trigger fired.'
GO
```

**Second is for Login:**

```
Alter TRIGGER user_confirmation ON ADMINISTRATOR

 FOR INSERT
 AS


  declare @ID varchar(20);
  declare @u_name varchar(20);

  declare @u_id varchar(20);
  set  @u_id= (select u_password from ADMINISTRATOR where u_name=@u_name);



  select @ID from Inserted I; 
  if(@ID=@u_id)

    print'Login Successfull'

 GO
```

I just want to call `trgAfterInsert` in `user_confirmation` trigger. Is it possible?

Comment: How exactly is this related to java or asp.net?

Comment: Put the code in a stored procedure, and call that from the triggers.

Comment: seems to me this is T-sql (microsoft) not PL/SQL (Oracle)

Comment: These triggers are flawed. YOu can not  set values from inserte to a scalar variable as it can contain multiple rows.

Comment: `inserted` and `deleted` are tables so that they can represent the results of set operations. Designing a trigger on the assumption that it  will always process exactly one row is generally a bad plan. If you are absolutely certain there will never be more than one row then _please_ add a check for the number of rows and use `RaIsError` or `Throw` to explicitly inform those who come along later that they have attempted to execute an unacceptable statement. (`if ( select Count(*) from inserted ) > 1 RaIsError( 'FooTable_Insert: No more than one row may be processed.', 25, 42 ) with log`)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call triggers directly.Triggers will be automatically fired based on your DML statements.Nested triggers are allowed and you have to change database setting for that.
please see below link for detailed info.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190739.aspx

DML statement on table A fires trigger a which in turns updates some table B causing trigger B to fire on that Table B

I dont think you have a need to for mutiple triggers,but rather call stored procs from button click event